# Implementing Class Weights for RNN in Keras with One Hot Coded Target

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have been researching how to implement class weights in a RNN structure where the model inputs in 14 days worth of data to predict the 15th day target and has same features for each day. Essentially the input is a 3d numpy array of size (sample size, 14, number of features). The target is simple binary classification "Yes or No", but one hot encoded. So the targets are [1 0] for "Yes" and [0 1] for "No".

Normally in a non-temporal model and non-one hot encoded response, keras has a simple implementation in the model fit function which you input a dictionary corresponding to the weights. For example:

{"Yes" : 1
"No" : 5}

Where misses on No will be weighted 5 times as much as a miss for Yes.

I have read you need to use sample weights when the temporal element comes into play, but I thought sample weights is for weighting different time steps (1- 14 days) differently. On top of this I am not sure how to deal with the one - hot encoding.

Any help would be appreciated, and if this is too complicated I might just write my own loss function and try it that way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For one hot encoded vectors the trick is to use sample_weight and weigh each sample as you would weight a class

```
import sklearn.utils.class_weight
```

pass class_weight dictionary to `sample_weights= class_weight.compute_sample_weight(class_weight,y)` and it produces weight for each sample based on the class.  This could be passed to keras `model.fit(...,sample_weight=sample_weights)`

in the case you don't have the class weights 
you could used `class_weight.compute_class_weight`, convert the output into a dictionary and pass to compute_sample_weight to get sample_weights vector